# Running process with Fabric hangs

Tags: python, fabric

I am having trouble running a process with Fabric. I have a program that runs and infinite loop E.g.

```
// loop.c
int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And I start this process with a start script:

```
#!/bin/sh
./loop &
```

This works fine is I just run ./start but I am trying to run it with a python script using Fabric (since in my actual scenario I want to run it on a remote machine). My python script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# imports ...

fabric.state.output['running'] = False
fabric.api.env.always_use_pty = False
fabric.api.env.host_string = "localhost"

command = "./start"
output = fabric.api.run(command)
```

My issue is when I run the python script it hangs on the run command and never returns. I can check with `ps -A | grep loop` and the process is running. If I manually kill the loop process then the python script finishes.

Any ideas on what I could be missing? Please let me know if more info/detail is required.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use `fabric.api.run('nohup ./loop')`